# OData table data display based on tile click in sapui5

Tags: xml, html, sapui5, tile

I have three tiles for different status in my XML view. When I click on a particular tile it should navigate me to a another XML where table data is displayed based on this status. I am able to navigate to the other view on tile click. But, my table displays all the data instead of displaying data for that particular status. I want to display open status data only when the corresponding tile is clicked:

[image: Tile View]

[image: Table View]

I display only the count of the status to the tile using `oModel.read()`.
The count to the Tile is displayed using the code

```js
oModel.read("/ServiceRequestCollection?$filter= CustomerID eq '1001192'", {
      success: function(oData, response) {
      var fld = [];
      fld = oData.results;
      var x = [];
      var count1 = 0;
      var count2 = 0;
      var count3 = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < oData.results.length; i++) {
      var p1 = "1001190";
      var obj = fld[i];
      if(x[obj.ProductID] === p1) {
      x[obj.ServiceRequestLifeCycleStatusCodeText] = [obj.ServiceRequestLifeCycleStatusCodeText];
      x[obj.ServiceRequestLifeCycleStatusCodeText].push(obj);
      // console.log(x);
      }
      if (fld[i].ServiceRequestLifeCycleStatusCodeText === "Open") {
      var OpenArray = [];
      count1 = count1 + 1;
      OpenArray.push(count1);
      OpenArray = {tilearray:OpenArray};
      var oVizFrame3Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(OpenArray);
      var oTile = oView.byId("opentile");
      oTile.setModel(oVizFrame3Model);
      oTile.setNumber(count1);
      // return OpenArray;
      } else {
      if (fld[i].ServiceRequestLifeCycleStatusCodeText === "In Process") {
      var InProcessArray = [];
      count2 = count2 + 1;
      InProcessArray.push(count2);
      InProcessArray = {tilearray:InProcessArray};
      oVizFrame3Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(InProcessArray);
      oTile = oView.byId("inprocesstile");
      oTile.setModel(oVizFrame3Model);
      oTile.setNumber(count2);
      // return TileData;
      }
      }
      if (fld[i].ServiceRequestLifeCycleStatusCodeText === "Completed") {
      var CompletedArray = [];
      count3 = count3 + 1;
      CompletedArray.push(count3);
      CompletedArray = {tilearray:CompletedArray};
      oVizFrame3Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(CompletedArray);
      oTile = oView.byId("completedtile");
      oTile.setModel(oVizFrame3Model);
      oTile.setNumber(count3);
      // return TileData;
      }
      }
      }
      });
```

The table data is loaded from a different array to that view. Please provide suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a filter to filter the data. I am showing you the code to do it for status as Open. Here 'iHome1' is the id of your table.

```
 var filters = [];

 var f1 = new  sap.ui.model.odata.Filter('CustomerID', [{operator:"EQ",value1:"1001192"}]);
 var f2 = new  sap.ui.model.odata.Filter('Status', [{operator:"EQ",value1:"SALESREP"}]);
            filters.push(f1);
            filters.push(f2);
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/ServiceRequestCollection",
                    false);
            var oHtable1 = sap.ui.getCore().byId("iHome1")
            oHtable1.setModel(oModel);
            oHtable1.bindRows({path:"/ServiceRequestCollection", filters: filters}  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Ajay. I tried something similar to your suggestion and got three separate array for each status. I am also able to get the event on which tile is clicked. What I am not able to do is bind a specific array to the table when the respective tile is clicked.

Comment: Say when the open tile is clicked I am able to bind only one of the 3 arrays. Please provide your suggestions whether I am going in the correct path or do I need to alter my code.

Comment: It would be very helpful if the experts provide suggestions for the same.